# How to use translateZ( ) transform with rotateY( ) using CSS?

Tags: html, css, rotation, translate

I was trying to use translateZ with rotateY to see clear differences but as soon as i hover the div the rotateY retrieves. The code is as follows-

```css
.box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  background: tomato;
  transform: rotateY(70deg);
  transition: transform 2s ease;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: perspective(500px) translateZ(300px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box">Some text</div>
</div>
```

This same thing also happens when i try to use translateX instead of Z. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `rotateY` on `:hover` as well because on `transform` property in `.box:hover` will override the `transform` property in `.box`

```css
.box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  background: tomato;
  transform: rotateY(70deg);
  transition: transform 2s ease;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: perspective(500px) translateZ(300px) rotateY(70deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box">Some text</div>
</div>
```